# Show full text in tooltip on mouseover

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have an input that I am binding long text to from **AngularJS**. I want to show an ellipsis, and on `mouseover`, show the full text in a tooltip.

Right now it shows the ellipsis, but you have to double-click it to have the full text pop up. The text is in a HTML table generated by `ng-repeat`.

```css
.long-value-input {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<input maxlength="250" id="input-{{$index}}" ng-click="setOptionsText(vehicle.optionAdjustment)" ; ng-model="vehicle.optionAdjustment" ng-disabled="disableOptionsField(vehicle)" style="width: 128px; height:35px; margin-left:5px;" class="options options-input long-value-input"
  ng-keypress="checkIfEnterKeyWasPressed($event, vehicle, 
    vehicle.optionAdjustment)" ng-blur="options(vehicle, vehicle.optionAdjustment);" />
```

How can I just mouse over the ellipsis and show the full text?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this :

```
.long-value-input {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.long-value-input:hover {
    width: auto;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 11;
}
```

Comment: i added background-color: red and with mousover it turned red(just to test) but no text

Comment: This might not work because im working with angular?

Comment: I never use AngularJS, I use Angular 2+ (which is different) but I don't think that the problem came from angular...Can you make a screen or pick an image from an other site to show me what you really want please :)

Comment: I think the problem came from the input, I already do this with a <p> or <span> but never w/ input

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) directive to toggle the value of a css rule on an element

```
ng-style="{'text-overflow': state ? 'ellipsis' : 'none' }"
```

Use [ngDblClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDblclick) to toggle that variable

```
ng-dblclick="state = true;"
```